# How do I setup recaptcha with a form which uses the php_self action

Tags: php, forms, curl, recaptcha

my site looks like this.

```
<?php
  include 'dbd.php';     //DB Login details
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head> 

<body>

<?php        
$showFormular = true;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = false;

    if (!$error) {
      $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (email, name) VALUES (:email, :name,)");
        $result    = $statement->execute(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $name
        ));

        if ($result) {
            echo "Your Registration was Successful";
            $showFormular = false;
        } else {
            echo 'Could not register your Account';
        }

    }
}

if ($showFormular) {
?>

<form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

    <input placeholder="Your Forum Name Here" name="name" required>
    <input placeholder="Your Forum Email Here" name="email" required>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public key"></div>

    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The Problem what I have is that I dont know how to implement the Serverside ReCaptcha Check. I tried it with the following method but there I get obviously the error that the function is empty because its getting executed directly.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST =>1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'secret' => 'privat key',
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        ],
]);
```

I hope I explained it good enough that someone can help me.

Comment: Where did you put that code you tried - inside the if that already checks if the form submit button is in the POST data …?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use curl command ? You can do this by directly with php code.

First of all download this php reCaptcha library and import your project :  [reCaptcha gitHub](https://github.com/google/recaptcha)

Secondly, after you action call your php and implement this on your php code.

```
require_once('your-imported-autoload.php-path'); ex:Assets/reCaptcha/autoload.php

  $privatekey = "-your private key-";

  $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($privatekey);

  $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],  

  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {

    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification

  }
```

For last, for cURL you are trying to connect through SSL and have to handle it

```
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```